# Python storing a list of class and exporting both

Tags: python

For my class below I am trying to get price data for two stocks by placing them in a list that will be run by my class.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

class price:
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.ticker = ticker
        company = yf.Ticker(self.ticker)
        price = company.history(period='max')
        price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
        price_df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False)

l = ['AAPL', 'KO']
for item in l:
    price(item)
```

when I export or print `price_df` I will only get the last entry in my list, i.e. only get "KO" price data without "AAPL" as well. The goal is to have "AAPL" price data directly followed by "KO" in one DataFrame. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the dataframe inside the class, I would suggest passing the list of tickers to the class & create the dataframe inside as well:

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

class Price:
    def __init__(self, tickers):
        self.tickers = tickers
        self.price_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for ticker in tickers:
              company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
              price = company.history(period='max')
              self.price_df.append(price)
        self.price_df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False)

l = ['AAPL', 'KO']
p = Price(l)
```